# How can I get two tables side by side in landscape mode?

Tags: tables, landscape

I'd like to get two tables side by side in landscape mode with an appendix title at the top. Here's what I've been working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\appendix{\large{\bf Appendix 4b: Overall Usage Statistics}}\\
\medskip



\emph{Table 1: Oriented to Bormino Usage}\\
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
Context & Italian & Bormino & Both & N/A \\\hline
\\
Mother & 24.3\% & 59.5\% & 16.2\% & 0\% \\
Parents to age 10 & 27.0\% & 59.5\% & 13.5\% & 0\% \\
Father & 29.7\% & 56.8\% & 10.8\% & 2.7\% \\
Grandfather & 24.3\% & 55.9\% & 10.8\% & 13.5\% \\
Grandmother & 24.3\% & 54.1\% & 13.5\% & 8.1\% \\
Brothers & 21.6\% & 46.0\% & 10.8\% & 21.6\% \\
Swearing & 27.0\% & 40.5\% & 16.2\% & 16.2\% \\
Sisters & 8.1\% & 35.1\% & 8.1\% & 48.7\% \\
Relatives & 24.3\% & 32.4\% & 43.2\% & 0\% \\
Neighbors & 24.3\% & 27.0\% & 46.0\% & 2.7\% \\
Partner & 32.4\% & 24.3\% & 27.0\% & 16.2\% \\
Son & 16.2\% & 21.6\% & 16.2\% & 46.0\% \\
Localities & 29.7\% & 21.6\% & 48.7\% & 0\% \\
At Work & 32.4\% & 21.6\% & 43.2\% & 2.7\% \\
Colleagues & 29.7\% & 18.9\% & 48.7\% & 2.7\% \\
Schoolmates & 43.2\% & 16.2\% & 32.4\% & 8.1\% \\
Thinking & 43.2\% & 16.2\% & 35.1\% & 5.4\% \\
Daughter & 13.5\% & 13.5\% & 8.1\% & 64.9\% \\
Officials & 67.6\% & 13.5\% & 18.9\% & 0\% \\
Praying & 40.5\% & 10.8\% & 16.2\% & 32.4\% \\
Counting/Mental math & 62.2\% & 8.1\% & 29.7\% & 0\% \\
Teachers & 73.0\% & 8.1\% & 5.4\% & 13.5\% \\

\end{tabular}


\emph{Table 2: Oriented to Italian Usage}\\
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
Context & Italian & Bormino & Both & N/A \\\hline
\\
Teachers & 73.0\% & 8.1\% & 5.4\% & 13.5\% \\
Officials & 67.6\% & 13.5\% & 18.9\% & 0\% \\
Counting/Mental math & 62.2\% & 8.1\% & 29.7\% & 0\% \\
Thinking & 43.2\% & 16.2\% & 35.1\% & 5.4\% \\
Schoolmates & 43.2\% & 16.2\% & 32.4\% & 8.1\% \\
Praying & 40.5\% & 10.8\% & 16.2\% & 32.4\% \\
Partner & 32.4\% & 24.3\% & 27.0\% & 16.2\% \\
At Work & 32.4\% & 21.6\% & 43.2\% & 2.7\% \\
Colleagues & 29.7\% & 18.9\% & 48.7\% & 2.7\% \\
Localities & 29.7\% & 21.6\% & 48.7\% & 0\% \\
Father & 29.7\% & 56.8\% & 10.8\% & 2.7\% \\
Swearing & 27.0\% & 40.5\% & 16.2\% & 16.2\% \\
Parents to age 10 & 27.0\% & 59.5\% & 13.5\% & 0\% \\
Neighbors & 24.3\% & 27.0\% & 46.0\% & 2.7\% \\
Relatives & 24.3\% & 32.4\% & 43.2\% & 0\% \\
Mother & 24.3\% & 59.5\% & 16.2\% & 0\% \\
Grandmother & 24.3\% & 54.1\% & 13.5\% & 8.1\% \\
Grandfather & 24.3\% & 55.9\% & 10.8\% & 13.5\% \\
Brothers & 21.6\% & 46.0\% & 10.8\% & 21.6\% \\
Son & 16.2\% & 21.6\% & 16.2\% & 46.0\% \\
Daughter & 13.5\% & 13.5\% & 8.1\% & 64.9\% \\
Sisters & 8.1\% & 35.1\% & 8.1\% & 48.7\% \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I've tried using minipage, but the two tables always appear on the left of the page on top of each other when I do this. Other options such as sidewaystable or column don't work either, they split the tables to two pages. I can't seem to find any other answers regarding side-by-side columns in landscape, so any advice would be useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your tables are quite wide, even in landscape mode, to fit next to one another. You could resize the tables (scale them down) to fit next to one another though, but that would decrease the font size. Would that be a viable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember that as soon as you leave an empty line, TeX will create a new paragraph and any following material will be typeset below. i have removed these and the tables typeset properly in landscape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
Context & Italian & Bormino & Both & N/A \\\hline
\\
Mother & 24.3\% & 59.5\% & 16.2\% & 0\% \\
Parents to age 10 & 27.0\% & 59.5\% & 13.5\% & 0\% \\
Father & 29.7\% & 56.8\% & 10.8\% & 2.7\% \\
Grandfather & 24.3\% & 55.9\% & 10.8\% & 13.5\% \\
Grandmother & 24.3\% & 54.1\% & 13.5\% & 8.1\% \\
Brothers & 21.6\% & 46.0\% & 10.8\% & 21.6\% \\
Swearing & 27.0\% & 40.5\% & 16.2\% & 16.2\% \\
Sisters & 8.1\% & 35.1\% & 8.1\% & 48.7\% \\
Relatives & 24.3\% & 32.4\% & 43.2\% & 0\% \\
Neighbors & 24.3\% & 27.0\% & 46.0\% & 2.7\% \\
Partner & 32.4\% & 24.3\% & 27.0\% & 16.2\% \\
Son & 16.2\% & 21.6\% & 16.2\% & 46.0\% \\
Localities & 29.7\% & 21.6\% & 48.7\% & 0\% \\
At Work & 32.4\% & 21.6\% & 43.2\% & 2.7\% \\
Colleagues & 29.7\% & 18.9\% & 48.7\% & 2.7\% \\
Schoolmates & 43.2\% & 16.2\% & 32.4\% & 8.1\% \\
Thinking & 43.2\% & 16.2\% & 35.1\% & 5.4\% \\
Daughter & 13.5\% & 13.5\% & 8.1\% & 64.9\% \\
Officials & 67.6\% & 13.5\% & 18.9\% & 0\% \\
Praying & 40.5\% & 10.8\% & 16.2\% & 32.4\% \\
Counting/Mental math & 62.2\% & 8.1\% & 29.7\% & 0\% \\
Teachers & 73.0\% & 8.1\% & 5.4\% & 13.5\% \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
Context & Italian & Bormino & Both & N/A \\\hline
\\
Teachers & 73.0\% & 8.1\% & 5.4\% & 13.5\% \\
Officials & 67.6\% & 13.5\% & 18.9\% & 0\% \\
Counting/Mental math & 62.2\% & 8.1\% & 29.7\% & 0\% \\
Thinking & 43.2\% & 16.2\% & 35.1\% & 5.4\% \\
Schoolmates & 43.2\% & 16.2\% & 32.4\% & 8.1\% \\
Praying & 40.5\% & 10.8\% & 16.2\% & 32.4\% \\
Partner & 32.4\% & 24.3\% & 27.0\% & 16.2\% \\
At Work & 32.4\% & 21.6\% & 43.2\% & 2.7\% \\
Colleagues & 29.7\% & 18.9\% & 48.7\% & 2.7\% \\
Localities & 29.7\% & 21.6\% & 48.7\% & 0\% \\
Father & 29.7\% & 56.8\% & 10.8\% & 2.7\% \\
Swearing & 27.0\% & 40.5\% & 16.2\% & 16.2\% \\
Parents to age 10 & 27.0\% & 59.5\% & 13.5\% & 0\% \\
Neighbors & 24.3\% & 27.0\% & 46.0\% & 2.7\% \\
Relatives & 24.3\% & 32.4\% & 43.2\% & 0\% \\
Mother & 24.3\% & 59.5\% & 16.2\% & 0\% \\
Grandmother & 24.3\% & 54.1\% & 13.5\% & 8.1\% \\
Grandfather & 24.3\% & 55.9\% & 10.8\% & 13.5\% \\
Brothers & 21.6\% & 46.0\% & 10.8\% & 21.6\% \\
Son & 16.2\% & 21.6\% & 16.2\% & 46.0\% \\
Daughter & 13.5\% & 13.5\% & 8.1\% & 64.9\% \\
Sisters & 8.1\% & 35.1\% & 8.1\% & 48.7\% \\
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

To space them a bit apart, you can use `hspace{<dimen>}`. For example to leave a 1em space use,

```
\end{tabular}\hspace{1em}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
```

Comment: It's so simple it's genius. Thanks so much. One question though -- how can I put a caption/label underneath each table like this?

Comment: @khelke You can enclose each in a minipage (dont't leave space between them) and use `\captionof{table}{...}` from the caption package. You were on the right track:)