# Centering two tables in landscape modus

Tags: tables, landscape

The posts seems very similar to the one's already posted [two tables side by side in landscape mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50479/how-can-i-get-two-tables-side-by-side-in-landscape-mode) but I have difficulties centering my first tables in the middle of a landscape page. This is only a script of my thesis which spans a lot of pages. As it is my whole thesis, I excuse the long preamble. I would like to fit in these two landscape tables below into my thesis. The tables are too big by nature, therefore I scaled them. How can I set the tables to be in the middle of the page. I have tried `\centering` in both, the `\table` and `\minipage` modus. I also tried it without `\table`,  but I wish one caption above both minipage tables. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{report} 
%========= PACKAGES
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%========= LAYOUT
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
%========= MATH
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%========= TABLES
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},  % do not treat "(" and ")" in any special way
         group-digits  = false} % no grouping of digits
%========= GRAPHICS
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%========= DOKUMENT =================
\begin{document}
\clearpage % begin landscape tables
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption[]{GARCH-VaR - out-of-sample estimates} \label{tab:VaRresultsgarch}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}
    S[table-number-alignment = right,
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 3]
    S
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = right,
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 3]
    S
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 4,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{*}]
    @{}}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GARCH} & & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{GARCH}\\
\cmidrule(rl){3-5} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
{\textbf{CHF}} & {Test} & {Normal} & {Std-$t$} & {GED} & {\textbf{EUR}} & {Test} & {Normal} & {Std-$t$} & {GED} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-5} \cmidrule(l){6-10}
\SI{5.0}{\percent} & {VR} & 5.213 & 5.611 & 5.054 & \SI{5.0}{\percent} & {VR} & 4.584 & 4.895 & 4.429 \\
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{minipage}\quad
%=========== new tabular =============
\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}
    S[table-number-alignment = right,
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 3]
    S
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = right,
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 3]
    S
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 4,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{*}]
    @{}}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GARCH} & & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{GARCH}\\
\cmidrule(rl){3-5} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
{\textbf{CHF}} & {Test} & {Normal} & {Std-$t$} & {GED} & {\textbf{EUR}} & {Test} & {Normal} & {Std-$t$} & {GED} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-5} \cmidrule(l){6-10}
\SI{1.0}{\percent} & {VR} & 1.512 & 1.114 & 1.114 & \SI{1.0}{\percent} & {VR} & 1.243 & 0.932 & 0.932 \\
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\clearpage
%=========== new page and tabular =============
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
%\caption{GARCH-VaR - out-of-sample estimates $p = 0.005$}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}
    S[table-number-alignment = right,
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 3]
    S
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = right,
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 3]
    S
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 4,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{*}]
    @{}}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GARCH} & & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{GARCH}\\
\cmidrule(rl){3-5} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
{\textbf{CHF}} & {Test} & {Normal} & {Std-$t$} & {GED} & {\textbf{EUR}} & {Test} & {Normal} & {Std-$t$} & {GED} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-5} \cmidrule(l){6-10}
\SI{0.5}{\percent} & {VR} & 0.836 & 0.358 & 0.398 & \SI{0.5}{\percent} & {VR} & 0.777 & 0.622 & 0.622 \\
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{minipage}\quad
%=========== new tabular =============
\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}
    S[table-number-alignment = right,
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 3]
    S
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = right,
    table-figures-integer = 1,
    table-figures-decimal = 3]
    S
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 3,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{**}]
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-integer = 2,
    table-figures-decimal = 4,
    table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{*}]
    @{}}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GARCH} & & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{GARCH}\\
\cmidrule(rl){3-5} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
{\textbf{CHF}} & {Test} & {Normal} & {Std-$t$} & {GED} & {\textbf{EUR}} & {Test} & {Normal} & {Std-$t$} & {GED} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-5} \cmidrule(l){6-10}
\SI{0.1}{\percent} & {VR} & 0.239 & 0.08 & 0.159 & \SI{0.1}{\percent} & {VR} & 0.233 & 0.078 & 0.078 \\
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please try to reduce your code as long as it still shows your problems. We have too much to read and try then. Please clarify if you are talking about horizontal or vertical centering.

Comment: Do you mean centering vertically? Add `\mbox{}\vfill` before `\begin{table}` and `\vfill` after `\end{table}`

Answer (score 1):

I ment to center the tables vertically. After several attempts I found the solution. When setting the table on an empty page the `\table` environment may not contain a positioning defined by `[htbp]`. 
By removing `[htbp]` the tables centered properly.

```
\clearpage

\begin{table}% ... [htp] <- remove
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
%\caption{GARCH-VaR - out-of-sample estimates $p = 0.005$}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}
% ...content
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Sorry for the post and hopefully this helps others.